# Prism Unity App Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, prism

I am trying to recreate my work environment at home so that I can practice MVVM some more and help some additional students who will be going and getting internships.  At work, we use Prism template pack in order to create views for our WPF applications.  I downloaded the Prism Template Pack from the url seen below...

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BrianLagunas.PrismTemplatePack

I fired up Visual Studio but I don't see the Prism Unity App project type under the Prism tab.  I do see the Prism Unity App as a recent project type, but when I click on that I cannot create a new project of that type because it says it no longer exists.  I have Visual Studio 2017 version 15.4.4 installed with the features .NET desktop development, Universal Windows Platform development, Data storage and processing and Xamarin.

Comment: Looks like you already have an answer to this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BrianLagunas.PrismTemplatePack#qna

Comment: Yes I asked it there as well.  I forgot to add that link after it was answered.  Thanks for posting the link though, for anyone who has the same 'issue' in the future!